# how to create calculation query in php?

Tags: mysql

I was trying to display a total sum without storing the `amount` and `total` inside the database I just did the operation and the result will be displayed in browser. I wanted to combine the query but I got error with

> 3 errors were found during analysis.

- An alias was previously found. (near "total" at position 109) An
  alias was expected. (near " " at position 108) Unexpected token.
  (near "total" at position 109)

below is the code that I have tried

```
SELECT ((`spercent` + `sharepercent`)/100) *`TransacAmount`  AS amount  AND (`TransacAmount` - amount) AS total
FROM sales_info
WHERE `id` ='00001'
AND `date`= '2020-09-28'
```

[Code I have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e6r4.png)

But I got error with

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND (`TransacAmount` - amount) AS total

This is the query that I tried to combined

```
SELECT ((`spercent` + `sharepercent`)/100) *`TransacAmount`  AS amount
FROM sales_info
WHERE `id` ='00001'
AND `date`= '2020-09-28'

SELECT(`TransacAmount` - amount) AS total
FROM sales_info
WHERE `id` ='00001'
AND `date`= '2020-09-28'
```

[Combined code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKHEL.png)

I don't want to duplicate the query so I decided to combined it. But I got it wrong and I'm not sure on how to fix this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: 'AND' is meaningless at this location.

Comment: i have post the code. If i can't use and how do I combined it?

Comment: Use comma to separate items in the `SELECT` list, not `AND`.

Comment: `SELECT calculation AS amount, othercalculation AS total ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT (((spercent + sharepercent)/100) * TransacAmount) amount
     , (TransacAmount - ((spercent + sharepercent)/100) * TransacAmount) total
  FROM sales_info
 WHERE id = 1
   AND date = '2020-09-28';
```

Unfortunately there's not an easy way to reference a variable that you create in the query. So you can't use what you've already calculated for the "amount" to then calculate the total.

Also, the tick marks (`) are not typically required in MySQL unless you're using special characters or reserved terms in your column names.